# Find each combination of values from a list of ranges in R

Tags: r

I am doing dynamic network analysis in R and I have a list of date ranges as two columns in a dataframe. I am trying to figure out how to create a comprehensive dataframe/list that contains every possible unique combination of every date within each range. The date ranges are all of different lengths.

For example:

```
Date1    Date2
1275     1277
1301     1303
1290     1291
```

I want to create a dataframe or list in which each column/item represents a unique possible combination of the dates within each of these ranges:

```
1      2      3      4      5      6      7...........?
1275   1276   1277   1275   1275   1275   1276........1277
1301   1301   1301   1302   1303   1302   1202........1303
1290   1290   1290   1290   1290   1291   1290........1291
```

My intuition from java is to turn to nested loops, but avoiding loops is like the whole point of R so I feel like I must be wrong in that intuition.

Based on
[R- all pairwise combinations of elements from two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895951/r-all-pairwise-combinations-of-elements-from-two-lists)
and
[Calculating all possible combinations within a range in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119761/calculating-all-possible-combinations-within-a-range-in-r)
I've hacked together this

```
makeAllDateCombos <- function(earlydatecolumn, latedatecolumn){
  allDCs <- NULL
  allDCs <- as.data.frame(lapply(earlydatecolumn, function(earlydatecolumn){
    lapply(latedatecolumn, function(latedatecolumn){
      (table(earlydatecolumn:latedatecolumn))
      })
  }))
  return(allDCs)
}

allTheDCs <- makeAllDCs(collab_dates$Date1, collab_dates$Date2)
```

However this returns an error.

```
Error in data.frame(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 16, 27, 6, 21, 26, 1, 5, 4, 31, 11, 18, 13, 15, 23, 17, 7, 10, 9, 24, 19, 33, 20
```

Comment: `t(do.call(expand.grid, mapply(seq, Date1, Date2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))` might work.

Comment: This is definitely on the right track. mapply(seq...) works, but the do.call(expand.grid, ...) crashes rstudio.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your suggestion. With a small list of ranges (under 5) your solution works perfectly, so if you want to submit it as an answer I'll accept it. With the amount of memory I have, I will need to find another solution, perhaps subsample of the total permutations, for figuring out how changes in dating affect the dynamic network metrics.

Comment: How large is the true source data? If you are aggregating or filtering that new matrix, it is possible to do a "lazy" `expand.grid` without exhausting memory and crashing R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With smaller numbers of combinations, this will work:

```
t(do.call(expand.grid, mapply(seq, Date1, Date2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))
```

Unfortunately, from your comment I infer that you have a relatively large number of combinations, thereby crushing the chance of dealing with all of your combinations at once. I suggest you may find use out of https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144255/3358272, slightly updated at https://gist.github.com/r2evans/e5531cbab8cf421d14ed. The point is to iterate over each combination and do something with it individually.